# Partly updated record

Tags: sql, hive

I have a target table and several increment tables in Hive. I have to add incrementl tables to target and add the new_id for every rows. If the old_id is equal I have to update the name, and process_date but the new_id has to be from previous row. Could you help me?

```
create table target (
    id           string,
    new_id           string,
    name         string,
    process_date string );


create table increment1 (
    id           string,
    name         string,
    process_date string );

create table increment2 like increment1;

insert into table increment1 values
('1', 'Apple', '2020-03-12'),
('3', 'Kiwi', '2020-03-12');


insert into table increment2 values
('3', 'Avocado', '2020-03-13'),
('4', 'Blackberry', '2020-03-12');
```

I tried to add with the script:

```
with a as (
    select coalesce(i.id, t.id)                     as id,
           coalesce(i.nk, t.new_id)                 as new_id,
           coalesce(i.name, t.name)                 as name,
           coalesce(i.process_date, t.process_date) as process_date
    from target t
             full join (
        select id,
               reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") as nk,
               name,
               process_date
        from increment1 -- increment2
    ) i on t.id = i.id
)
from a
insert overwrite table target
select *;
```

After the first insert I got next data in target:

```
1       89296ec9-cc0f-4f50-a3dc-22cdaa61f707    Apple   2020-03-12
2       5cd1a5f7-7f86-4daa-8b68-1db5a33a14f8    Orange  2020-03-12
3       2513bd6d-1947-4b41-a033-58ec25c78313    Kiwi    2020-03-12
```

And after the second I got next data in target:

```
1       89296ec9-cc0f-4f50-a3dc-22cdaa61f707    Apple   2020-03-12
2       5cd1a5f7-7f86-4daa-8b68-1db5a33a14f8    Orange  2020-03-12
3       df683397-c02e-4e6f-a09a-ad2d95f6b797    Avocado 2020-03-13
4       854df396-b345-499b-aa9b-6a6b0b84a92f    Blackberry      2020-03-12
```

And new_id was changed for row with id = 3. How to left it old?

```
3       2513bd6d-1947-4b41-a033-58ec25c78313    Avocado 2020-03-13
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you are trying to update/insert(incremental load) on target. You can use `merge` statement to do this:

```
merge into target t
using ( select * from increment1) sub
on sub.id = t.id
when matched then update set t.name = sub.name, t.process_date= sub.process_date
when not matched then insert values (sub.id, sub.name, sub.process_date);
```

If you're not trying to do this, please add more context and expected result

Comment: Thank u for response, but I work with Hive version less than 2.2